# Expectation of squared integral over distribution

Tags: distributions, expected-value, integral

Right now, I have some function $g(x,\theta)$ where the expectation this function at a given $x$ evaluated over $\theta$ $E_\theta[g(x,\theta)]$ is known, and I want to upper bound (or compute if at all possible) $I=E_\theta\left[\left(\int g(x,\theta)^\frac{1}{2}\,dP_x \right)^2\right]$

What I tried:

First divide up the integral as a double integral $I=E_\theta\left[\iint g(x,\theta)^\frac{1}{2} g(y,\theta)^\frac{1}{2}\,dP_xdP_y \right]$ where $x$ and $y$ have identical distributions, then pull in the expectation $I=\iint E_\theta\left[g(x,\theta)^\frac{1}{2} g(y,\theta)^\frac{1}{2}\right]\,dP_xdP_y $. Then, split the expectation by the product $I=\iint E_\theta\left[g(x,\theta)^\frac{1}{2}\right] E_\theta\left[g(y,\theta)^\frac{1}{2}\right]\,dP_xdP_y $, and then use Jensen's equality to finish with $I<\iint E_\theta\left[g(x,\theta)\right]^\frac{1}{2} E_\theta\left[g(y,\theta)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\,dP_xdP_y$, where this bound is computed by Monte Carlo approximation in $x$ and $y$

However, I am not sure about the assumptions I've made in getting to the end result, nor do I feel this bound is very sharp or efficient- did I make any mistakes along the way, and/or is there a better way of handling this?

Edit: Sorry, the expectation was with respect to some hyperparameter of function g, I've edited it in the first sentence, though the rest has been left as-is

Edit 2: So a bit more information on g: essentially, what I was unsure about was the application of certain integration rules to the integral over $P_x$, in order to pull another expectation in. As mentioned before, I forgot to mention that the expectation was with respect to another variable (defining g) rather than over $P_x$, so I've tried to make the notation a bit more explicit.

Some context on $g$ (I am not sure how much this changes things, but for the sake of completion): this expectation function was originally intended to be the misclassification probability for a point $x$ classified by a Gaussian Process model in level set estimation. Specifically, $g=(I_{f(x)\leq0}-I_{\hat{f}(x)\leq0})^2$, where $\hat{f}$ is some GP approximation of an unknown true function $f$ sampled from to create the GP. Then, $E_\theta[g(x)]$ is the expectation of this error over realizations of the GP, which has expression $1-\Phi(|\mu(x)|/\sigma(x))$, where $\Phi$ is the Gaussian CDF, and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the GP mean and standard deviation.

Comment: The integral is already non-random, it is pointless to embrace it with an expectation operator.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the problem: The expectation is with respect to some random hyperparameter for the function $g$, which is why I need to reduce the integral to some form where I have E[g(x)] as I can't compute it in a tractable manner otherwise.

Comment: Please make that more clear in your post, George.  Perhaps you could explicitly indicate that hyperparameter in your notation for $g.$  I suspect your problem, or part of it anyway, stems from that lapse in notation.  Even then, there doesn't look like there's enough information here for us to supply any help at all, because you tell us nothing at all about $g.$

Comment: I've added some more context regarding it, though ultimately I was wondering about the validity of the manipulations I did to pull the expectation into the integral over P_x, separate from actually evaluating the expectation

Comment: I don't see how you factored the inner expectation; $g(y,\theta)$ is not independent of $g(x,\theta)$ as far as I can see.

Comment: I would use Cauchy-Schwarz if you insist on doing things this way. What is the purpose of the bound?